# Meaning of "furniture"

Tags: vocabulary

What does Mary Karr mean by the word *furniture* in the sentence: "But when you're a kid and something big is going on, you might as well be furniture for all anybody says to you"?

Comment: It means what it normally means: a chair, a table, a couch. Who talks to those?

Answer (score 1):

The writer means that you're treated as a part of the background, and not a person deserving of attention, consideration, or conversation. We sit on chairs and lean on tables, without paying much attention to them, without wondering how they're understanding or reacting to conversations or activities taking place in their midst. Similarly, she's saying that adults treat kids as not seeing, thinking, feeling, idea-having beings when "something big is going on."